# How to load dynamically many markers with Leaflet using VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, vue2leaflet

I have a webapp that displays many markers on a map that are loaded dynamically when the user moves the map around. I call an API with the bounds and get back a list of markers.

#### The current solution

```
<l-map v-if="showMap" :zoom="zoom" :center="center" @update:bounds="boundsUpdated" style="height: 100%">
    <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"/>
    <l-marker v-for="marker in markers" :key="marker.id" :lat-lng="marker.coordinates" >
      <l-icon
          icon-url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png">
      </l-icon>
    </l-marker>
</l-map>

...

mounted() {
    let thisClass = this;
    EventBus.$on('new_markers', function (payLoad) {
      for (const marker of payLoad) {
        thisClass.markerMap[marker.id] = marker;
      }
      thisClass.markers = Object.values(thisClass.markerMap)
    });
  },
```

Based on how slow it is to render the markers and how hot my laptop gets, I assume it is rendering all the markers every time.

#### My question

How to load with leaflet only the markers that are new in the list of markers and not the entire list every time?

Comment: `only the markers that are not yet in the list of markers` if they're not in the list of markers, where are they?

Comment: I updated my question to be more precise. From the API I get different markers based on the zoom level, and the bounds. This is why I think I would be more efficient to only add to the map the new markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I assume it is rendering all the markers every time` -> Have you tried to console.log `markers` to see how many items are inside ?

If you want to display on the map just the markers that are new to the markers array, what you could do is changing `v-for="marker in markers"` to `v-for="marker in lastMarkers` with `lastMakers` being a computed property returning only the last items, like so:

```
lastMarkers() {
 return this.markers.slice(this.lastMarkerIndex);
}
```

now you need to update `lastMarkerIndex` in your EventBus callback function just before assigning `Object.values(thisClass.markerMap)` to `thisClass.markers`

And to get rid of `thisClass` and use `this` instead you can just use an arrow function for your callback, instead of `function (payload)`

So to sum up your EventBus listener could look like this :

```
EventBus.$on('new_markers', (payload) => {
  for (const marker of payload) {
    this.markerMap[marker.id] = marker;
  }
  this.lastMarkerIndex = this.markers.length - 1;
  this.markers = Object.values(this.markerMap)
});
```

This is how I would do but I guess there are a lot of different ways to achieve what you want.